# "Error in col2rgb(colors, alpha = TRUE) : invalid RGB specification" when running HeatmapAnnotation() (from ComplexHeatmap)

Tags: r, bioconductor, heatmap, complexheatmap

*This question was also asked on [github](https://github.com/jokergoo/ComplexHeatmap/issues/913)*

I'm trying to run the function HeatmapAnnotation (a function in the ComplexHeatmap package). When I run it, I get the error "Error in col2rgb(colors, alpha = TRUE) : invalid RGB specification"

col2rgb() is not among the libraries I've loaded and it doesn't seem to be a method contained in HeatmapAnnotation.

Here's the code block for the section:

```
df <- data.frame(labid= combmetadata$Sample_Name,
             Diagnosis= combmetadata$Diagnosis,
             Tissue = combmetadata$Tissue,
             Tumor.Normal = combmetadata$T.N,
             study = combmetadata$batch)

 labid <- colnames(bValsselect)
 df <- left_join(as.data.frame(labid),df,by="labid")
 df <- df[,c(2,4,5)]
 df$study[df$study == "1" | df$study == "2"] <- "cgid"

 df$Diagnosis <- factor(df$Diagnosis, levels = c("Uterine endometrial","Ovarian endometrioid",
                                            "Ovarian mucinous",
                                            "Colorectal mucinous",
                                            "Pancreas mucinous",
                                            "Stomach mucinous"))

 ha_column = HeatmapAnnotation(df = df, 
                          col = list(Diagnosis = c("Uterine endometrial" = "#DDCC77F",
                                          "Ovarian endometrioid" = "#0F7554",
                                          "Ovarian mucinous" = "#44AA99",
                                          "Colorectal mucinous" = "#882255",
                                          "Pancreas mucinous" = "#AA4499",
                                          "Stomach mucinous" = "#D695D0"),
                            Tumor.Normal = c("N" = "grey",
                                             "T" = "black"),
                            study = c("cgid" = "#332288",
                                      "tcga" = "#BD9AF7")))

hegt <- Heatmap(bValsselect,
            column_split=4,
            name = "Beta Value",
            col = colorRamp2(c(0,0.25,0.5),c("#00FFCC","#FFFFFF","#0099FF")),
            show_row_names = FALSE, 
            top_annotation = ha_column,
            show_row_dend = F)
```

The code runs fine up until it reaches the end of the HeatmapAnnotation() call

I've tried to load col2rgb() and override the alpha setting. Can anyone give me a clue about what's happening and any suggestions on how to correct the problem?  I'm running R 4.2. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ComplexHeatmap/versions/1.10.2/topics/SingleAnnotation), it seems that `HeatmapAnnotation` expects a vector, whereas you are giving it a list. It is not clear on what acceptable color types are. It might even work with a list, but I'd suggest playing around with what you are supplying as your `col` parameter.

Note that `HeatmapAnnotation` has to do color mapping of some kind, the [code](https://github.com/jokergoo/ComplexHeatmap/blob/master/R/HeatmapAnnotation-class.R) is a little dense, but it does look like it calls out to `SingleAnnotation`, [which in turn runs `ColorRamp2`](https://github.com/jokergoo/ComplexHeatmap/blob/master/R/SingleAnnotation-class.R#L495-L507), which does use `col2rgb`.

It also looks like `col2rgb` is called in `ColorRamp2`, which you use in the `Heatmap` call. How sure are you that your script isn't making it that far? It would help to see error output, possibly.

That said, when I take your isolated `ColorRamp2` and run it, it goes ok. Possibly pull out the `ColorRamp2` call and run it yourself in your environment to make sure nothing weird is happening.

Try moving the assignment of the colors outside the `Heatmap` call, occasionally supplying function calls as parameters like that causes issues.

Comment: You're right about the chain of calls.  I do know that the code didn't run past the HeatmapAnnotation() function because in the process of debugging it, I could generate the error before I run the Heatmap() subblock.  However, I just realized that the problem is that the first color assignment contains 7 alphanumeric characters instead of 6.  That's what was causing the function to fail.  Thanks for your help though.  It certainly helps me understand the function a little better.

Answer (score 0):

The alphanumeric value for the first color assignment contains 7 alphanumeric characters instead of 6. Correcting this typo fixed the problem.